# Fortran - lbound throws error 6366 "The shapes of the array expressions do not conform"

Tags: fortran

So I've been confounded again by Fortran. Go figure. Anyway, I'm trying to write a pretty simple routine the strips values off the end of an array. Everything complicated works fine, except I want to write the subroutine such that I don't have to pass the lower bound of the input array to it. Here is the subroutine:

```
    subroutine Strip(list,lstart, index)        
        implicit none 
        integer :: i, index, isize, tsize, lstart, istart
        real, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(inout) :: list
        real, dimension(:), allocatable :: tlist             
        isize = size(list)             
        tsize = index-1                
        print *, 'index', index 
        print *, 'isize', isize
        print*, 'lbound', INT(lbound(list))
        print*, 'tsize', tsize      
        istart = lbound(list) !<---- This lines throws the error 
        !These are commented out because everything below here works 
        !allocate(tlist(lstart:tsize))
        !tlist = list(lstart:index-1)
        !deallocate(list) 
        !call move_alloc(tlist,list) 
    end subroutine Strip
```

Right now I'm passing the lower bound of the input list into the subroutine (lstart), but I'd like not to do that. Anyway, this code doesn't compile, the compiler throws the error `6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform [ISTART]`

I don't know how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which compiler is this? Different compilers have different error messages.

Answer (score 1):

`Lbound()` returns an array! Read The Fortran Manual (RTFM) at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/LBOUND.html

It returns an array with as many elements as is the rank ("dimension" 1D,2D,...) of the array.

To get a single number, for a specific dimension, use the optional argument DIM.

```
istart = lbound(list, 1)
```

Comment: I literally read a tutorial thing that said it returns an integer. Wtf. Thanks for the help, I'll get back to you if this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Okay so that fixed that problem, but now the use of "deallocate(list)" and "move_alloc(tlist,list)" throw access violation errors. I also don't know how to fix that. Can you help?

Comment: Are tsize and index-1 the same value?  You don't need either the allocate or the deallocate here - the assignment to tlist will do the allocation (you're using ifort, so use version 17 or add -standard-semantics). Similarly, the move_alloc will deallocate list. My guess is that you've corrupted memory somewhere. Adding -CB to the compile might help, but ifort doesn't yet do shape checking at run-time.

Comment: Soooo....how should I change the function to fix my problems? And ya index-1 and tsize should be the same.

Comment: Hard to say without the complete code. This is a different problem and deserves a different question. I agree with the above recommendations of Steve Lionel.